# Swift, button part is outside view, and i wont handle events

Tags: ios, swift

So i have a layout in swift:

basically the greyed out part of the selected button wont handle events, i tried:

```
bottomView.bringSubview(toFront: startButton)
```

But its not working, im new to swift, but im thinking its because
the greyed out part is outside de UIView and thats why it can't handle the event. Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: that button belongs to what UIView? can you post your UIView hierarchy?

Comment: @ReinierMelian, actually this was the way to fix it, i changed the hierarchy of the button, to the parent UIView, and constrained the button to the place i wanted it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Is the button over the grey area view(kind of Z index)? You can always verify if the button is above the view in storyboard's Document outline (that is on left).
Below is a sample view in a view controller. Look at how rabbitButton is over the snailButton

[image: Sample image with views]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here :

- Make sure that your gray view is at the top of the view stack. To do that, identify your parent view and : `parentView.bringSubview(toFront: grayStartView)` just as you did. So the only thing you need to make sure in your case is that `bottomView` is indeed the parent view of `grayStartView`.
- If `grayStartView` is a `UIView` or a `UIImageView` and not a `UIButton`, then you need to make sure that it allows user touches, by using : `grayStartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`.
- Now it might sound trivial but just in case make sure that you add the target properly if its a button : `grayStartButton.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(yourMethod), for: .touchUpInside)` or a view : `grayStartView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourMethod)))`.
- Also you need to make sure that, if you add any subview to your grayStartView, or your grayStartButton, you need to call `subviewOfGrayButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` otherwise the subview would then absorb the touches.
- Finally I would check that your method (especially the `sender`) is properly written :

```
@IBAction func yourMethod(sender: UIButton) {    
   // ... Do some cool things here 
}
```

If it's still doesn't work, well it would be helpful to learn more about your view hierarchy :)

Note: From what I can see it seems like you're missing a width constraint here (or maybe is it intentional?) so even though it's not related to your problem you may want to check this as well